# The dual transformation has the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

**The Question:**

Let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $\Bbb F$.

(i) Prove that $\text{Im}(T')=(\text{Ker}(T)) ^ \circ$

(ii) Deduce that $\text{dim}(\text{Im}(T))=\text{dim}(\text{Im}(T'))$

(iii) Hence, deduce that, if $T:V\rightarrow V$ and $T':V' \rightarrow V'$, then $T$ and $T'$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues with the same multiplicities.

---

**Notes:**

$T':V' \rightarrow W'$ is the dual transformation of $T$ defined by $T'(f) = f(T)$

$(\text{Ker}(T)) ^ \circ$ is the annihilator of $\text{Ker}(T)$

---

**My Attempt:**

Individually, I am able to do these questions using whatever method available to me. Unfortunately, the words "hence" and "deduce" mean that I have to use previous parts of the question.

I was able to do (i), and deduce (ii) from (i).

Any hints on how to "hence, deduce" (iii)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We let $I:V \to V$ be the identity on $V$ and $I’ : V’ \to V’$ be the identity on $V’$. Let $\lambda I: V \to V$ be the map that multiplies any element by $\lambda$. Note that the dual map $\lambda I’ : V’ \to V’$ is also given by multiplication by the same number. You can see this by noting $\lambda I’ (f) = f(\lambda I) = \lambda f(I)$. Now since we know $dim(Im(T)) = dim(Im(T’))$, it follows that $dim(Im(T- \lambda I)) = dim(Im((T - \lambda I)’))= dim(Im(T’ - \lambda I’))$. By rank-nullity, it follows that $dim(ker(T-\lambda I)) = dim(ker(T’-\lambda I’))$. This last equation expresses that the number $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if any only if it is an eigenvalue of $T’$, and moreover, the dimensions are equal so they have the same multiplicities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, mind if you explain why the dimensions of the kernels being equal implies that the multiplicities are equal?

Comment: For example, if the matrix of $T$ was \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} its characteristic equation is $(x-1)^2$ so the eigenvalue $-1$ has multiplicity $2$. But not every vector in $\Bbb R^2$ is an eigenvector (say $(0,1)$) so the dimension of $\text{Ker}(T+I)$ is not $2$

Comment: OK, I suppose the question meant *geometric* multiplicity and not *algebraic* multiplicity